# Notation: Set of all functions with finite number of variables from $A$ to $B$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, notation

The setting here is basic set theory. We denote by $B^A$ the set of all functions from $A$ to $B$. Also, to describe a function with $n$ variables, such that the variables come from $A$ and the function takes values in $B$, we can use $A^n$, the set of all $n$-tuples taking values in $A$ (formally - The set of all functions from $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$ to $A$).

So $B^{A^n}$ is the set of all functions of artity $n$ from $A$ to $B$.

The question: what is the **standard notation** (or notations) for the set $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B^{A^n}$, the set of all functions of arity at least 1 from $A$ to $B$?

Arity of at least 0 is also good (maybe $B^{A^*}$ is used in this case?)

Comment: I will use some shorthand notation for sure (yours is good). I just want to check if there isn't already some standard notation.

Comment: You may want to consider whether you really need that set. For many purposes it is easier to identify each univariate function with a bivariate function that is constant in the second variable, etc.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is a standard notation for that. In any case, $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty B^{A^n}$ is pretty clear but considering just using words and a simpler notation such as ${\cal F}(A,B)$.