# Distributing $n$ elements into $m$ groups

Tags: combinatorics

I have a $n$ elements $x_1,\dots,x_n$ that have to be assigned to $m$ containers $Y_1, \dots, Y_m$. The containers can be empty.

How many arrangements, say $c_{m,n}$ are there?

**example**

Let $m\triangleq 3$ and $n \triangleq 2$, then there are $c_{3,2}=9$ possible arrangements
\begin{equation*}\begin{array}{lll}
Y_1 =\{x_1,x_2\} &Y_2=\varnothing &Y_3=\varnothing \\
Y_1 =\varnothing &Y_2=\{x_1,x_2\} &Y_3=\varnothing \\
Y_1 =\varnothing &Y_2=\varnothing &Y_3=\{x_1,x_2\} \\
Y_1 =\{x_1\}     &Y_2=\{x_2\}     &Y_3=\varnothing \\
Y_1 =\varnothing &Y_2=\{x_1\}     &Y_3=\{x_2\}     \\
Y_1 =\{x_1\}     &Y_2=\varnothing &Y_3=\{x_2\}     \\
Y_1 =\{x_2\}     &Y_2=\{x_1\}     &Y_3=\varnothing \\
Y_1 =\varnothing &Y_2=\{x_2\}     &Y_3=\{x_1\}     \\
Y_1 =\{x_2\}     &Y_2=\varnothing &Y_3=\{x_1\}     \\
\end{array}
\end{equation*}

Comment: $|\{1,\dots,m\}^{\{1,\dots,n\}}|=m^n.$ [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4598731)

Comment: In your example $n=2, m=3$, we have $3$ choices of containers for the first element, similarly $3$ choices for the second element, so in total you multiply them together to get $3^2=9$ choices. This is easily generalised to $m^n$.

Comment: Considering each element $x_i$, there are $m$ containers, so $m$ choices of where each element can go. Multiplying these together by the number of elements, $n$. yields $m^n$.